# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time' in django save function

Tags: python, django

I have these model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    """
    Event Model
    """
    day = models.DateField(u'Day of the event',
                           help_text=u'Day of the event', null=True)
    start_time = models.TimeField(
        u'Starting time', help_text=u'Starting time', null=True)
    end_time = models.TimeField(
        u'Final time', help_text=u'Final time', null=True)
    end_day = models.DateField(
        u'End Day of the event', help_text=u'End Day of the event', null=True)
    total_minutes = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
```

I want to calculate diffrence between the minutes of two `TimeFields` 
So  I have done the following:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    start = datetime.combine(self.day, self.start_time)
    end = datetime.combine(self.end_day, self.end_time)

    diffrence = end - start
    self.total_minutes = diffrence.total_seconds() / 60

    super(Event, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

but getting the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time`.

Can anyone tell me why I am getting the error?

Comment: those are datetime objects, not time, Use django `DateTimeField`

Comment: Is there any possibility that I can get the diffrence between time using `TimeField`

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#timefield

Comment: Use `datetime.time`

Comment: You are getting this error because, as the error message clearly states, `datetime.time` objects do not support substraction. Now this doesn't match your code snippet (which is using `datetime.datetime` object, which do support substraction), so if you expect any useful answer; post your real code AND the full matching traceback.

Comment: As a side note: unless you have a really compelling reason to do so, you should NOT store informations that can be computed from existing fields (relational model normalization rules) - you will end up with inconsistant data if anyone changes any field value without going thru your model's `save()`, and your DB is perfectly able to do this computation by itself. Also, you should not use separate `DateField` and `TimeField` to store a full datetime, just use a plain  `DatetimeField`.